# Merge two list randomly returns a strange merged list

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I've just started to learn Racket and I need to create a procedure that merge two list randomly.

This is my code:

```
#lang racket
(define merge-randomly
   (lambda (lst1 lst2)
      (cond ((and (null? lst1) (null? lst2)) null)
            ((null? lst1) lst2)
            ((null? lst2) lst1)
            (else
               (cond ((> (random) 0.5) (cons (cons (car lst1) (car lst2)) (merge-randomly (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2))))
                     (else (cons (cons (car lst2) (car lst1)) (merge-randomly (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2))))
               )
            )
      )
   )
)
```

I need to use with list like these two:

```
(define l1 '((1 2 3) (7 8 9)))
(define l2 '((4 5 6)))
```

I need to create a new list like this one:

```
'((4 5 6) (1 2 3) (7 8 9))
```

But I get this list:

```
'(((4 5 6) 1 2 3) (7 8 9))
```

I'm doing something wrong, probably here, `(cons (cons (car lst1) (car lst2))`, or here, `(cons (cons (car lst2) (car lst1))`, at the else instruction in first `cond`.

How can I get the list I want to get?

Comment: I'm wondering, is "randomly" what you really want in the end? Functions that branch randomly like this, while they aren't intrinsically bad, they are harder to write Unit Tests for. If you're learning Racket I would recommend writing functions which you can unit-test easily, or even which you can write examples for before writing the body of the function.

Comment: @AlexKnauth Thanks for your comment. How can I write unit test for Racket? I'm studying at the university and I'm doing what the professor is asking for. I think that if I append both lists will be good enough.

Comment: The normal way is using [`check-equal?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html#%28def._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._check-equal~3f%29%29) from RackUnit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. The format for `cons` is this:

```
(cons first-element rest-of-the-list)
```

So, when you use `(const '(4 5 6) '(1 2 3))`, it returns `((4 5 6) 1 2 3)`.

The correct format for what you are trying to do would be:

```
(cons (car lst1) (cons (car ls2) (merge-randomly (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2))))
```

and similarly for the second case.

Here's what the final function should look like:

```
(define merge-randomly
   (lambda (lst1 lst2)
      (cond ((and (null? lst1) (null? lst2)) null)
            ((null? lst1) lst2)
            ((null? lst2) lst1)
            (else
               (cond ((> (random) 0.5) (cons (car lst1) (cons (car lst2) (merge-randomly (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))))
                     (else (cons (car lst2) (cons (car lst1) (merge-randomly (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))))
               )
            )
      )
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `(cons (cons (car lst1) (car lst2)) ...)`. Change it to `(cons (car lst1) (cons (car lst2) ...)`.

PS Your closing parentheses are not idiomatically placed.